# HttpClient truncate response content

Tags: c#, xml, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I did some request using `httpclient`. One with `Content-Type:application/json` and the other one with `Content-Type:application/xml`.

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
request.Content = new StringContent(BodyContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Result = responseText.ToString();
client.Dispose();
request.Dispose();
```

This code works perfectly when content type is `json`, but sometimes return truncated response contents when it comes from content type `xml`. That in my case, returned string content from `json` longer than `xml`.

Here example of response [example.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9xOAWKNoW2GcjdGWFNaQS1rYWc)

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us an example of truncated response? Do you get the same issue if you call the endpoint from Postman? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Are you in control of the server in this instance. Have you compared them both using a proxy like Fiddler?

Comment: @mjwills it too long to paste in here.. it like xml data, but then truncated in the middle of element value. When I try on postman, it has little chance to meet this condition. But when do it on visual studio debuger, it mostly happen

Comment: Honestly, it will be harder to help you without seeing that XML.

Comment: The server may be sending http1.1 (chunked) rather then http1.0 (one stream).   The file may also be GZIP.  Using fiddler like ste-fu suggested will tell the answer.  Also with fiddler check status from response if you are getting 200 Done (successful) or something else.